# A conceptual understanding of Filtrations and Martingales

Tags: probability, martingales, filtrations

I am an engineer by training and trying to self-study Martingales by myself. I came across the concept of a natural filtration and I have a conceptual question.

Suppose that $X_1,X_2,X_3,\cdots$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. The natural filtration is understood to be $\mathcal{F}_i = \sigma(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_i) $.

This definition confuses me. If my understanding is correct, "$\sigma(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_i)$" is the "smallest sigma-algebra such that each of the random variables $X_j, j=1,2,3,\cdots,i$ is measurable with respect to it."

Since each $X_k$ has the same distribution, dosen't this imply that $\sigma(X_1) = \sigma(X_1,X_2) = \sigma(X_1,X_2,X_3) \cdots $?

While we are on this topic, I read that a random variable is simply a mapping between sample spaces and the real line. So, if all random variables in the sequence $X_1,X_2,X_3,\cdots$ are defined on the same probability triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathcal{P})$ and have the same distribution, does this also imply the "functions" or "maps" $X_i :\Omega \to \mathcal{R}$ and $X_j : \Omega \to \mathcal{R}$ are one and the same? Then, what is the meaning of independence?

Comment: Two random variables can have the same distribution without being the same function. This happens all the time when we have independent and identically distributed random variables. For example, imagine tossing a coin twice. Let $X$ be equal to $1$ if the result of the first toss is heads and $0$ otherwise, and let $Y$ be equal to $1$ if the result of the second toss is heads and $0$ otherwise. Then $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed but they are not the same function.

Comment: Aah, I understand your example. Thanks !! Could you comment on the question about natural filtrations as well?

Comment: If you consider $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure and define $X_N(\omega)$ as the $n-$th coefficient in the expansion of $\omega)$ with respect to base $2$ then it can be shown that $(X_n)$ is an i.i.d sequence. There is  no reason why random variables have to be equal just because their distributions are.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you, this is a nice example! Would you care to comment on the question of natural filtrations?

Comment: Once again, if random variables have the same distribution it does not follow that they generate the same sigma algebra. In my example above you can explicitly write down $\sigma (X_1)$ and $\sigma (X_2)$ and see that they are not equal. @VinayakSuresh

Comment: Thank you, I see it now. This kind of an example seems important enough to be explicitly stated in textbooks.